# SWIFT - How to get connection of an object in table cell to change attribute of it from another object in table cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableView for shopping cart.
Each TableCell has a UITextField for product quantity and UILable for sub total.

When the quantity change, sub-total should be changed as well.
However, I do not know how to get the specific UILable selector to change subtotal.

Example: 
In jQuery, I can get a selector like the following code.
$('.subTotalUI').eq(index).text("$" + newPrice)

I got the an index of cell by using following code but I am still not sure how to change the price.

```swift
cell.ccQuantity.tag = indexPath.row
cell.ccQuantity.addTarget(self, action: #selector(quantityChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

@objc func quantityChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(textField.tag)
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

```swift
import UIKit

class cartTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var ccImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ccQuantity: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ccName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ccSubtotal: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ccExplain: UILabel!
}
class CartViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var cartTableView: UITableView!

    fileprivate let items:[product] = products().getData()
    fileprivate var cart:cart = Registry.instance.liveCart

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "BACK", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        self.cartTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false;
        self.cartTableView.delegate = self
        self.cartTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cart.items.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:cartTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell", for: indexPath) as! cartTableCell
        let eachCartItem = cart.items[indexPath.row]
        let thisQty = eachCartItem!.quantity
        let thisPrice = eachCartItem!.price
        let thisProduct = items[eachCartItem!.no]
        cell.ccName.text = thisProduct.name
        cell.ccImage.image = UIImage.init(named: thisProduct.image)?.imageWithBorder(width: 2, color: UIColor.black)
        cell.ccQuantity.delegate = self
        cell.ccQuantity.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.ccQuantity.addTarget(self, action: #selector(quantityChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        cell.ccQuantity.text = String(thisQty)
        cell.ccSubtotal.text = "$" + String(format: "%.2f", Float(thisQty) * thisPrice);
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }

    @objc func quantityChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(textField.tag)
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbNch.png)

Comment: This isn't a good approach; as cells are reused you will keep adding the action handler. Each cell should handle the update and then inform the view controller via a delegation pattern or closure.

Comment: Than you for the your advise but I am so beginner of SWIFT. Could you provide some example codes for me ? It would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cellForRow method to achieve your required functionality

```
 @objc func quantityChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(textField.tag)
       let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: textField.tag, section: 0)) as! cartTableCell             // get cell
 let eachCartItem = cart.items[textField.tag]             //get data from array
    let thisQty = eachCartItem!.quantity
    let thisPrice = eachCartItem!.price
    let thisProduct = items[eachCartItem!.no]

//below you can change what ever you want to change now

    cell.ccName.text = thisProduct.name
    cell.ccImage.image = UIImage.init(named: thisProduct.image)?.imageWithBorder(width: 2, color: UIColor.black)

    cell.ccQuantity.addTarget(self, action: #selector(quantityChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    cell.ccQuantity.text = String(thisQty)
    cell.ccSubtotal.text = "$" + String(format: "%.2f", Float(thisQty) * thisPrice);
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    }
```

Comment: Cool ! This is what I want to know. Thank you. /////// let cell = self.cartTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: textField.tag, section: 0)) as! cartTableCell; cell.ccSubtotal.text = "Change"